# javascript alert somehting I am having trouble with

Tags: javascript, alert

```
alert(currentObject.position.x);
alert(incrementPositionX);
alert(currentObject.name);
currentObject.position.x += incrementPositionX;
alert(currentObject.position.x);
alert(incrementPositionX);
alert(currentObject.name);
```

When this Threejs javascript code runs the first 3 alerts are 10 .5 cube1
then after the 1 statement the next 3 alerts  are 100.5 .5 cube1

How could the position go from 10 to 100.5 if the increment is .5?
This is a sporadic occurrence.  after this is run once it works correctly!

Cannot figure this out thanks for the help; Probably something obvious

Comment: `currentObject.position.x` is not a number but a string the first time.

Comment: FYI: using `console.log(variable)` with a browser's developer tools open is significantly easier to use for debugging than `alert`

Comment: Or just use the developer tools in the inspector. In Chrome you just find your code in the sources menu, click the line to add a breakpoint, (probably reload the page, and then) hover over the variable to see its current value. That way you don't have to remove a bunch of `console.log` lines.

Comment: thanks that was the problem ;  appreciate the suggestions!